# custom InputFormat, hadoop c++ pipes

Tags: hadoop

I'd like use hadoop c++ pipes to create my may/reduce code. And the input data is binary, I want to custimize the inputformat to control getSplits logic...... but am unsure if that's a possible solution. I tried assign my custom inputformat class in cli but failed to run.

```
../bin/hadoop pipes -conf testframework.xml -input input -output output -inputformat TestInputFormat.class
```

i got below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestInputFormat.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:812)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.getClass(Submitter.java:372)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.run(Submitter.java:421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.main(Submitter.java:494)
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is just the .class at the end. But if you already tried removing it. You could try what I did to solve this. I packed into a .jar (`jar cf libJar.jar packageName`). I used -libjars to reference to it, and `-inputformat packageName.TestInputFormat`. I hope this helps.

**Edit 1**

Another way is using `-D mapred.input.format.class=packageName.TestInputFormat`